# How to use similar package and command keys, should they be separate or the same variable?

Tags: expl3, key-value

I am writing a `expl3` package for typesetting amino acid residues and I am still getting to grips with LaTeX3 and the interfaces documentation. I have looked at the `nicematrix` [annotated code](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix) for inspiration as it is a well put together package but it is also a long document and I do not understand it fully. I have options that can be set at package loading but I also want them to be customisable when calling specific commands. What can be done in this situation, should I use the same variables that are set in the package options and put in a

```
\group_begin:
\keys_set:nn { AminoSymb / resid } { #1 }
...
\group_end:
```

block to not overwrite the global package options or is it good practice to use different variables i.e. `\l_aminosymbols_text_font_size_tl` for the package option and `\l_aminosymbols_resname_text_font_size_tl` for that specific command?

I'm concious this question may be seen as opinionated and I would agree but I haven't seen anything similar on this site (although wouldn't mind a duplicate if I have missed it) so hopefully it could be helpful to future readers. This is perhaps quite basic to experienced users but I want my first package to be the best to my ability so I hope this is fine.

Current output:

[image]

How the code looks using different variables:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{aminosymbols.sty}

\ProvidesExplPackage
  {aminosymbols}
  {}
  {}
  {Typesetting amino acid abbreviations with residue numbers and symbols}

\NewDocumentCommand { \aasp } { O{} }
  {
    \IfValueTF { #1 }
    {
      \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { AminoSymb / resid } { #1 }
      \cs_if_exist_use:c { \l_aminosymbols_resname_text_font_size_tl }
      This \c_space_tl is \c_space_tl a \c_space_tl MWE
      \group_end:
    }
    {
    This \c_space_tl is \c_space_tl a \c_space_tl MWE
    }
  }

\keys_define:nn { AminoSymb / resid }
  {
    fontsize .tl_set:N  = \l_aminosymbols_resname_text_font_size_tl,
    fontsize .initial:n = normalsize,
  }

\tl_new:N \l_aminosymbols_text_font_size_tl

\keys_define:nn { AminoSymb / Package }
  {
    fontsize .tl_set:N   = \l_aminosymbols_text_font_size_tl,
    fontsize .initial:n    = normalsize,
  }

\cs_if_exist:NTF \ProcessKeyOptions
  {
    \ProcessKeyOptions [ AminoSymb / Package ]
  }
  {
    \RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
    \ProcessKeysOptions { AminoSymb / Package }
  }

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fontsize=scriptsize]{aminosymbols}

\begin{document}
\noindent\aasp{}

\noindent\aasp[fontsize=huge]{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you're using the variables the keys set for the same thing (e.g. the size of the font used for a particular kind of thing), I'd keep them the same and use a local group, provided it's OK to use locally set variables in whatever you're doing. Otherwise, you'll just end up with more complicated and less clear code, which can't be a good thing. Since it is common to set variables to some default, it seems perfectly reasonable to make that default configurable through package options.

Comment: I tend to use `\group_begin:` and `\group_end:` routinely when defining new functions, unless I have reason not to or the function will only be called internally by something which does the grouping. Keeping things local by default seems sensible to me. But I don't know if this is the correct approach or not.

Comment: It depends on the use case, but, imho (and agreeing to @cfr), keeping things local and using the exact same key-set is the easiest approach. If you need keys that are only available while the package is loaded use the `.usage:n` property.

Comment: @cfr if you wanted to post an answer, I would happily upvote, thank you and Skillmon for the feedback I am taking them on board in my TeX file :)

Comment: @JamesT Done. By the way, I believe `siunitx` is *the* model package for `expl3` coding. However, I don't know how you're supposed to find this out. A member of the LaTeX3 team told me, but I'm not sure if it is documented anywhere.

Comment: Instead of using `\c_space_tl` to introduce spaces between words, you can use `~` in `\ExplSyntaxOn`: `This~ is~ a~ MWE` will give the same output, but is semantically cleaner (inside `\ExplSyntaxOn` a `~` is the same as a normal space outside of `\ExplSyntaxOn`, not a non-breakable space).

Comment: @Skillmon I didn't know that was how it worked in `expl3`, thank you for that, I just assumed it was the same as normal LaTeX, will change my package :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a dabbler in `expl3`, so this answer is categorically non-authoritative.

## *Caveat emptor ...*

If you're using the variables the keys set for the same thing (e.g. the size of the font used for a particular kind of element), I'd keep them the same and use a local group, provided the way you're using them doesn't require them to be set globally.

Introducing two sets of keys and two sets of variables for the same thing will just complicate your code and make it harder for both you and others to follow, which can't be a good thing. While possibly negligible, it's also an unnecessary use of resources such as memory.

Since it's common to set variables to some default, it seems perfectly reasonable to make that default configurable through package options, which is essentially what you'd be doing.

`clsguide.pdf` says

> `.usage` – defines whether the option can be given only when loading
> (`load`), in the preamble (`preamble`) or has no limitation on scope
> (`general`) (page 16)

So the key-value interface for class and package authors is explicitly designed to allow a key to be defined once for use as both a package option and wherever else it might be required in the document. Just make the scope `general` for keys which you want to function in this way.

I tend to use `\group_begin:` and `\group_end:` routinely when defining new functions, unless I have some specific reason not to or the function will only be called internally by something which does the grouping. So I'd probably write

```
\NewDocumentCommand { \aasp } { o }
{
  \group_begin:
    \IfValueTF { #1 }
    {
      \keys_set:nn { AminoSymb / resid } { #1 }
      \cs_if_exist_use:c { \l_aminosymbols_resname_text_font_size_tl }
      This ~ is ~ an ~ MWE
    }
    {
    This ~ is ~ an ~ MWE
    }
  \group_end:
}
```

Keeping things local by default seems sensible to me. But I don't know if this is the correct approach or not.

Comment: Minor correction: If you want to use `\IfValueTF` you need to use the `o` type argument, not `O{}`.

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks. I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: it was also present in the MWE of the question -- which I noticed only after the comment under your answer :)

Comment: @Skillmon I know. That's where it came from, but I should've noticed. (I'd be unlikely to write it unless I was very tired.) Do you think I should change the spaces, too? I'd write `~`, which I noticed you mentioned above.

Comment: The more code applying best practice, the better. So yes, I'd change it (future visitors might not notice the comments).

Comment: @Skillmon Done, thanks.